# GA4 Data API - compound dimension filters on audienceName field are ineffectual

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

#### Problem

I'm using the GA4 Data API v1beta via the Node.js client library (`googleapis` package). Specifically, I'm hitting the [runReport](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport) endpoint.

I'm running into an issue where compound (e.g. `orGroup`) dimension filters on the `audienceName` field won't take effect. Some context follows.

#### What works

If I use just a simple/primitive filter on `audienceName` things work as expected. Example request body:

```js
{
    dimensions: [{
      name: 'audienceName',
    }, {
      name: 'eventName',
    }],
    metrics: [{
      name: 'sessions',
    }],
    dimensionFilter: {
      filter: {
        fieldName: 'audienceName',
        stringFilter: {
          value: "Purchasers",
        }
      }
    },
    dateRanges: [
      {startDate: "...", endDate: "..."}
    ]
}
```

This results in a response containing only those points where `audienceName == "Purchasers"`, as expected.

#### What doesn't work

If I introduce a complex filter on `audienceName`, specifically using `orGroup`, the filter becomes ineffectual. Example request:

```js
{
    dimensions: [{
      name: 'audienceName',
    }, {
      name: 'eventName',
    }],
    metrics: [{
      name: 'sessions',
    }],
    dimensionFilter: {
      orGroup: {
        expressions: [
          {
            filter: {
              fieldName: 'audienceName',
              stringFilter: {
                value: "Experiment Control",
              }
            }
          },
          {
            filter: {
              fieldName: 'audienceName',
              stringFilter: {
                value: "Experiment Variation",
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    dateRanges: [
      {startDate: "...", endDate: "..."}
    ]
}
```

I would expect this to return only those points for which

```
(audienceName == "Experiment Control") || (audienceName == "Experiment Variation")
```

However this is not the case. The response contains points from *all* audiences that exist in the given property.

#### Conclusion

I tested this using different fields to see if I was misunderstanding the way that complex expression were meant to work. Namely, if I use a similar filter (`orGroup`) on the `eventName` field, things work as expected. So it seems that the `audienceName` field specifically is not honoring complex expressions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could try using "IN_LIST" which would enable you to use a single filter.